Check if any list item match variable
The goal is to verify if the string matches any of list item.
This is opposite to CHECK IF VARIABLE EXISTS in the list
Code should be similar to:
email="john.brown@google.com"
list=["app-1", "app-2", "john"]

if [ $email -contains $list]; then
  echo "email contains variable from list"
else
  echo "email does not contain any of list items"
fi

# Item1: false -> email does not contains "app-1"
# Item2: false -> email does not contains "app-2"
# Item3: true  -> email contains "john"


checking if a string exists in an array of strings in bash is a close fit -- not quite a match because substrings are acceptable.

...whereas something that is a proper match is check if a string contains element of array with a shell script. (Granted, they're using && there to combine the results, but the important missing piece behind this question -- being able to do substring matches on content found by iterating through an array -- is present)

Try with:
#!/bin/bash

email="john.brown@google.com"
list=("app-1" "app-2" "john")

found=false

for item in "${list[@]}"; do
  if [[ $email == *"$item"* ]]; then
    echo "Found!"
    found=true
    break
  fi
done

if [ $found == false ]; then
  echo "Not found."
fi


[ $found == false ] is better written as be [ "$found" = false ]. Yes, we know that in this particular case [ will be an extended one with (nonstandard) support for == as a comparison operator, and that found will always have the exact string true or false... but better practice to demonstrate code that will work in other shells and handle surprising circumstances (like when IFS contains characters from either true or false) correctly.
